# matlibplot polyfit to subset of x values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I have x and y data in a dictionary object in the form {'item1': (x,y), 'item2': (x,y) ...} where each x and y value is a list of 100 numbers. 
For each key, my x values go from 0 to 50. I want to fit a straight line to the data based only on the data which x>=10 and x<=20. 
This is what I am trying...

```
for key,value in Dict.iteritems():
   #Get x,y values from each key in turn.
   [x,y] =  Dict.get(key) 
   # Extract just the x values in range. 
   xFit = [i for i in x if (i>=10 and i<=20)]

   << yFit = Get the corresponding y values for xFit >>   

   p = polyfit(xFit, yFit, 1)
```

Is there a nice way to fit a line to the [x,y] data within the desired range? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform both `x` and `y` in a `np.array`, which will make the conditional slicing easy using fancy indexing:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
cond = (x>=10) & (x<=20)
xFit = x[ cond ]
yFit = y[ cond ]
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. That helped a lot. I'm new to python, so thanks for not replying with a "read the documentation" type answer! :)